# MQ series with vert.x

Tags: ibm-mq, vert.x

How can I implement an application that sends and receives messages through an MQ series queue, using qmanager and channel in the connection with newer versions of vert.x?

I hope to do something like this, but newer versions of vert.x mqtt don't allow me to do it.

```
Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx();

        // Crear una instancia del cliente MQTT
        MqttClient client = vertx.createMqttClient();

        // Configurar el cliente MQTT
        MqttConnectOptions options = new MqttConnectOptions().setQmanager("my-qmanager").setChannel("my-channel");
        client.connect("tcp://localhost:1883", "my-client-id", "my-password", options, result -> {
            // Procesar el resultado de la conexión
            if (result.succeeded()) {
                // La conexión se realizó correctamente

                // Crear un consumidor para la cola de entrada
                client.subscribe("entrada", qos -> {
                    // Procesar el resultado de la suscripción
                    if (qos.succeeded()) {
                        // La suscripción se realizó correctamente

                        // Registrar un handler para el consumidor
                        client.consumer("entrada", message -> {
                            // Procesar el mensaje recibido
                            System.out.println("Recibido mensaje: " + message.body());
                        });
                    } else {
                        // La suscripción no se realizó correctamente
                        System.err.println("Error al suscribirse a la cola: " + qos.cause());
                    }
                });

                // Crear un productor para la cola de salida
                client.publish("salida", "Hola Mundo", qos -> {
                    // Procesar el resultado de la publicación
                    if (qos.succeeded()) {
                        // La publicación se realizó correctamente
                        System.out.println("Mensaje publicado correctamente");
                    } else {
                        // La publicación no se realizó correctamente
                        System.err.println("Error al publicar el mensaje: " + qos.cause());
                    }
                });
            } else {
                // La conexión no se realizó correctamente
                System.err.println("Error al conectar al broker MQTT: " + result.cause());
            }
        });

        // Ejecutar la aplicación
        vertx.run();
    }
```

Comment: provide stacktrace or alike to prove the `don't allow` point

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about vert.x but did vert.x switch to MQTT v5.0?

IBM MQ only supports up to MQTT v3.1.1:
https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.3?topic=reference-mq-telemetry-transport-format-protocol

So, if there is a configuration or setup parameter that tells vert.x to use MQTT v3.1.1 protocol then change to to MQTT 3.1.1 or simply use the previous release of vert.x